# Apigee API Platform: INVALID_PROXY Error

Tags: apigee

We are using Apigee as our API proxy and we are getting INVALID_PROXY error in our test environment. This error is inconsistent but shows up 90% of the time.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<fault>
     <faultstring>"Invalid proxy";</faultstring>
     <detail><errorcode>INVALID_PROXY</errorcode></detail>
</fault>
```

Can somebody from Apigee team share the cause of the problem? I could not find any documentation on Apigee website related to this error code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At runtime **INVALID_PROXY** error is shown when the router component at Apigee is not able to find the proper api proxy resource info. As you are saying if its inconsistent, it could be a deployment issue. If you can provide the org, env and api proxy details i can verify that at my end.

As a workaround you can also try **redeploying** you api proxy and see if you are facing this issue or not.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I suspect system updates on Apigee's side might have caused this issue. Now we are not facing this problem. In case I face it again, I'll try to redeploy and if the problem persists then will post it here.

Answer (score 1):

This error is related to improper deployment of bundle
I would suggest use "maven"/"APIGEE Edge Management APIs" for deployments.These tools wuld provide proper visibility into deployment status.Avoid using UI for deployments.

Answer (score 0):

Proxy validation is done when you try to import the bundle. We can only import bundles in `.zip` format. If you are seeing this error while trying to import and you are using a `zip` file, please share the bundle you are using so that we may have a closer look.

Comment: We are not getting this error while importing the bundle. We are getting this error while making a call to the authorization resource that we have created on Apigee Platform.

Comment: @NitinArora it would be helpful if you can share your bundle with us.We can analyse the error returned and come back with the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to improper deployment of bundle I would suggest use "maven"/"APIGEE Edge Management APIs" for deployments.These tools wuld provide proper visibility into deployment status.Avoid using UI for deployments